# Mudar src da iframe e postar data com javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

eu tenho um script a onde o muda o src da iframe por java script (tem que ser por esse methodo), porem não sei como enviar dados por post somente por get pois é so por os dados na url alguem sabe como fazer isso

```
<div id="overlayedt" >
    <iframe id="frameEditor" src="" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;background:white"></iframe>
</div>
```

Java script

```
function editfile(a,b,c){
    $("#frameEditor").attr('src','<?php echo $s; ?>/manager/editor/?a='+a+'&b='+b+'&c='+c+'',{aa:'oii'});
    $("#overlayedt").show();
}
```

ja tentei colocoar os dados via post com o `{key:value}`
igual no `$.post()` mas nada

Comment: Qual seria o problema de usar get? Se realmente precisa ser POST, um jeito bem simples é um form com campos hidden, cujo target seja o iframe.

Comment: no get os dados ficam mais visível entente

Comment: e o seguinte é que é um editor de arquivos (tipo o cpnael) para que você possa entender melhor, o programa lista pastas e arquivos e depois se for arquivo editavel o usuario pode editar online nesse caso  é passado para a função a path do  arquivo e o nome para que o  sistema. so que está via get e quria somente via poste, não achei  nada na internet relativo a isso

Answer (score 3):

Segue um exemplo bem simples de como mandar um POST para um `iframe`:

HTML

```
<form id="formulario" action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post" target="destino">
  <input type="hidden" id="campo" name="campo">
</form>
<iframe name="destino"></iframe>
```

JS

```
setInterval ( function(){
  document.getElementById("campo").value = Date();
  document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
}, 2000 );
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/GqEakX)**.

Usei a data no campo como exemplo, para mudar o `src` e qualquer outro campo, a lógica é a mesma.